# How to get a string from a list of properties of an object?

Tags: javascript

I want to reduce the array of properties of an object into a string, below is my code snippet.

```js
let obj = {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'thomas', age: 26}
let keys = ["firstname", "age"]
let string = keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc = obj[curr] + " - " + obj[curr];
  return acc;
}, "");

console.log(string)
```

Currently getting `26 - 26`

The expected string I am looking is `John - 26`

I tried with placing **acc**, but it didn't work. Also, I know I have given "" (empty string) as the start value, but no luck.

How can I achieve the above output?

Comment: Typo? `obj[curr] + " - " + obj[curr];` is twice the same property...

Comment: i tried with obj[curr] + " - " + obj[acc], but didn't worked

Comment: Still, why would you think it would work by any chance by concatenating exactly the same thing

Comment: i put it because if use acc, then it will be undefined. So in case of better understanding

Answer (score 4):

Use `map` and `join` instead of `reduce`:

```js
let obj = {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'thomas', age: 26};
let keys = ["firstname", "age"];
let string = keys.map(curr => obj[curr]).join(" - ");

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just edited your code. You were not joining the previous value.

```js
let obj = { firstname: "John", lastname: "thomas", age: 26 };
let keys = ["firstname", "age"];
let string = keys.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if(i === 0) acc += obj[curr];
  else acc += " - " + obj[curr];
  return acc;
}, "");

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Having to strip the trailing `" - "` makes this a little ugly.

Comment: @jarmod is it okay now?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, the value of `curr` is always the current item in the array. So, in the line of your code, `acc = obj[curr] + " - " + obj[curr]`, the value of `curr` will always be the same for each iteration.

Try this out -

```
let obj = {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'thomas', age: 26}
let keys = ["firstname", "age"]
let string = keys.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (index < keys.length - 1) {
        acc += obj[curr] + ' - ';
    } else {
        acc += obj[curr];
    }
    return acc;
}, '');
console.log(string);
```

I took the liberty to add an `if condition` so you can avoid an extra `-` at the end of the string.